# React input style only works at 100% zoom on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I am trying to add radio buttons to a React project, and running into an issue where the style for certain input elements (radio and checkbox) does not get applied on the chrome browser if the zoom level is anything other than 100%. For Safari and Firefox, the style works fine for all zoom levels.

I have checked this website https://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/#ie6-xp and I see the same issue with the radio buttons there.

[image: style working]

[image: style not working]

I see the same behavior with checkbox elements. Also zooming out to 90% or lower has same behavior.

```
  renderButtons = (options) => {
    return [
      ...options.map(v =>
      <div key={v} style={{display:'flex', width:'50%', 'lineHeight':'35px'}}>
        <label style={{'marginRight':'10px'}}><nobr>{v}</nobr></label>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          value={v}
          checked={this.props.valueSelected === v}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        ></input>
      </div>)
    ];
  };
```

Comment: Radio buttons can be challenging to stylize properly in my experience. I would suggest creating your own buttons that simply resemble radio buttons and apply changes as necessary to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Digglit I see the same issue with checkbox element also, not just radio button.

Comment: I was thinking more of creating a div say 25x25px throwing on a border-radius it. That div houses another div say 15x15px with a black background with opacity: 0 that changes to opacity: 1 on click if that makes sense

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rb1wfyh2/

Check out that fiddle. That is what I had in mind